# install4j update JRE without generating new installer

Tags: java, install4j, antivirus

We use installer with embedded JRE. To update JRE we generate new installer and use auto-update feature. But antiviruses (Windows Defender,..) warn user that it is new file which was downloaded only few times. How to update JRE without creating new installer to avoid antivirus warnings.

Answer (score 0):

This is a warning related to the code signing certificate that you are using, not to the particular file. After users from a sufficiently large number of IP addresses have downloaded executables signed with this certificate, the warning will no longer be displayed.

The only way around this is to use an extended code signing certificate which is immediately trusted by the Windows SmartScreen filter.

Comment: We create a new installer and sign it with the same certificate. It looks like it is the new installer file that is causing the warning popup. It would be great to be able to update only the components - the built-in JRE or Java application, not the full installer.